# File-based bitmap API's

Tags: c++, c

I want to write changed sectors on volume in bitmap. I don't think that it is good to use in memory bitmap because volume can
be extremely large and large amount of RAM will be constantly occupied. I think that file based bitmap(bitmap in file on disk) will be optimal. Performance hit will be considerably softened the windows cache manager. Windows have a lot of classes to operate with memory bitmaps
(bit array), but i can't find ready to use implementations of file based bitmaps. 
For example I need void that can set some bits(from n to k) in this file. A can write but i prefer to use ready lib. Do you know some 
routines, apis or libs for this? I accept c or c++, user or kernel mode.

Comment: How large do you expect your bitmap to be?

Comment: @Yexo. How large can be user volume? Maximum volume size for ntfs 2^32 clusters. So can have up to 2^32 bits in bitmap

Comment: Assuming 4kb sector size and 1TB volume size, there is "mere" 256 million sectors. If you use 1 sector = 1 px, with 256-bit color the bitmap will be 256MB big, with 32bit color it's 1GB. Still manageable in memory. I doubt there is any framework for efficient handling of such big bitmaps, but writing a BITMAPINFOHEADER and then dumping the buffer seems to be the most efficient solution.

Comment: @Agent_L I really don't think "bitmap" here refers to an image.

Comment: @unwind exactly. not image. array of bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Now that you've said the size of your bitmap is 2^32 bits, just use normal allocation. With 64 bit processes allocating a GB is not a problem.

Firstly I'm going to assume you're using 64 bit. If your not, switch as it simplifies things a lot when working with large files.

If the bitmap is larger than is reasonable to store in the page file (>20-50GB) use a persisted memory mapped file, otherwise just use normal allocation. A memory mapped file provides the advantages of keeping the data in memory but without the downside of requiring large amounts of paging space as the file is used as a separate page file.

If the file is small enough to fit in you address space (128TB on 64 bit) then you can just map the entire file whilst if it is larger then you just have to map in the part that your working on.

For how to map a file into memory see: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: i need to save this bitmap before reboot, wan't memory mapped files better for this then normal allocation + serialization/desiarilization? want memory sonsumption will be worst with in memory bitmap if i will write/read randombly often from bitmap?